# Mobile battery percent determining program

Tags: mobile

How does a mobile phone determines the percentage of battery left? Is it related to quantum physics?
I think that it run some kind of test to determine its efficiency at the time and on the basis of results, it determines the battery left. Please also send some coding for this.

Comment: Everything is related to quantum physics to some degree...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does a mobile phone determines the percentage of battery left?

It measures the voltage supplied by the battery. Since the battery's voltage drop usually isn't linear, the device likely does some processing to map the measured voltage onto a linear "percent lifetime remaining" scale, with 0% corresponding to the voltage at which the device can no longer operate.

Similarly the charging circuit monitors the battery voltage during charging and either stops charging or switches to a trickle charging process when the battery is "full," meaning that the voltage has stopped increasing over time.